# Adding an additional column header row in middle of kable?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I am trying to add an additional header row in a long kable. Below is an example of what my current table looks like:

[image]

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I have not been able to find any description of this. If anyone has any ideas how I might accomplish this it would be much appreciated.

Code for kable table:

```
library(kableExtra)

my_data <-  mtcars[1:8, 1:6]
kable(my_data, booktabs = TRUE, align = "c", table.attr = "style='width:100%;'") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped"), position = "center", full_width = FALSE) %>%
  group_rows("Set1", 1, 4) %>%
  group_rows("Set2", 5, 8)
```

It's not very important that the final table looks *exactly* like the image, if the header row is another full row or something like that, that is totally fine. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't there's a "kable" way of doing it. Here I mimicked your output by adding the column names as a row in `my_data`, then use `row_spec` to decorate that row.

```r
library(kableExtra)

my_data <-  mtcars[1:8, 1:6]

my_data <- rbind(my_data[1:4,], 
                 as.data.frame(rbind(colnames(my_data)), row.names = "Set2") |> 
                   setNames(colnames(my_data)), 
                 my_data[5:nrow(my_data),])

kable(my_data, booktabs = TRUE, align = "c", table.attr = "style='width:100%;'") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped"), position = "center", full_width = FALSE) %>%
  group_rows("Set1", 1, 4) %>%
  add_indent(6:9) %>% 
  row_spec(5, bold = T, extra_css = "border-bottom: 1px solid")
```

[image: kable_row_spec]